# Display inline bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, angular

Estoy abriendo una modal con un mapa de google maps el problema que tengo es que al abrir la modal el mapa no se centra donde yo quiero esto es debido a que no coge el height según encontré por internet, así que fuí a ponerle un height pero me dice lo siguiente.

> height no tiene ningún efecto en este elemento ya que su valor de "display" es inline.

Sin embargo si le agrego inline-block mi mapa de google maps desaparece de la ventana modal. Si el mapa lo saco fuera de la modal si que se centra y coge el height.

Este es mi mapa

```
 <agm-map #agmMap [zoom]="8" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [fullscreenControl]=true [mapTypeControl]="true" (triggerResize)="true">
     <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
```

Esta en mi modal:

```
<!-- Modal mapa -->
<div class="modal fade" id="map-google" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" style="z-index:9999999;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{url_foto_titulo}}</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{url_foto_cabecera}}</h4> -->
        <h4 style="color: gray; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; ">{{url_foto_cabecera}}</h4>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="mapa">
                <agm-map #AgmMap [zoom]="8" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [fullscreenControl]=true [mapTypeControl]="true" (triggerResize)="true">
                    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
                </agm-map>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{url_foto_pie}}</h4> -->
        <h4 style="color: gray; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; ">{{url_foto_pie}}</h4>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="resizeMap()">kjkjkjkjkjk</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Con esto la abro:

```
 <i *ngIf="empleado.latitud_salida != 0 && empleado.longitud_salida != 0" class="fas fa-street-view fontawensome" (click)="geolocalizacion_salida(empleado.fecha, empleado.hora_entrada, empleado.hora_salida, empleado.nombre, empleado.apellidos,empleado.latitud_salida, empleado.longitud_salida);resizeMap()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map-google"></i>
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Necesitarás poner el mapa en un elemento div al que asignarle un valor de height. Si con eso no te funciona por favor pon el resto del código así podemos ver cómo estás inicializando el modal y el tipo de modal que estás usando.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Narshe agregué el div mapa y le puse height 300 pero sigue sin centrarse... y sin dejarme aplicarle height al <agm-map>

Comment: Cómo asignaste el alto del div mapa? Supongo que quieres centrarlo verticalmente. Para ello basta con asignar un `height` al contenedor principal (debe tener `position: relative`), luego puedes aplicar al iframe las siguientes propiedades: `position: absolute; top: 50%;  transform: translateY(-50%);`

Comment: Quiero darle a <agm-map un height para que cuando se abra mi mapa se centre en las coordenadas que le e puesto